# list of blog engines written in python

Tags: python, blog-engine

Can I get a list of popular blog engines written in python?

google didn't help much!

Comment: I bumped into a blog engine in Python which is written by a google employee. But I lost the link, would be happy if someone can post it here...

Comment: I found it after a long search, and now I added it to that list below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about this list:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonBlogSoftware

Although I can't speak to how popular any of these are.

also among the popular static site generators written in python that are missing from the above list.

- Hyde: http://ringce.com/hyde (now being developed at https://github.com/hyde/hyde)
- Pelican: http://pelican.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- Blogofile: http://www.blogofile.com

Comment: that was extensive! And thanks very much for the answer :)

Comment: As of mid-2012 blogofile is being actively developed again.

Comment: @P.T. updated to reflect your comment